# How do I customize order information on Shopify Thank-you page?

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to customize the text content that appears below the order ID. The default verbiage I'm trying update is "An email receipt containing information about your order will soon follow ...". I tried tech support but they didn't seem to have any good ideas. I found a good page on customizing the thank you page but it was all about putting additional content on the page rather than modifying some of the built-in verbiage. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to modify the checkout text by creating a custom language.

See this tutorial: [Customize checkout language](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/checkout/checkout-language)

1. Go to Admin > Settings > Checkout
2. Scroll down to Checkout Language and click on "Create a new translation"
3. Find the field you want to change and add your custom text

[image: Customize checkout language]

4. Hit Save and go back to the Checkout settings and make sure your new translation is selected in the the drop down. (If not, select it and hit Save again.)
5. Now your custom text will appear in your store's checkout.

Note: If you only change one field in your new translation, all the others will stay the same as the default language.